# How to Upload a pdf into FTP Server in R?

Tags: r, server, ftp, upload

I want to upload a pdf into a folder in a ftp server and I'm using this function.

```
ftpUpload("D:/Info/Example.pdf","ftp://example@example.com:pswexample@serverexample.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/example.pdf")
```

This is the function parameters

```
  ftpUpload("Localfile.html", "ftp://User:Password@FTPServer/Destination.html")
```

But when I run the code I have this error message

> Error in Function (type, msg, asError = TRUE) Access denied: 530

Can anybody help me? Thanks a Lot.

Comment: It may not be obvious (nor correct?) that this is referring to `RCurl::ftpUpload`.

Comment: I think the extra `@` in your username is likely a problem, though you'll need to dig into the execution to see what is being used where. (My *guess*: you'll need to dig deep, since debugging `RCurl::curlPerform` did not reveal parsing of the username/password out of the URL. I suspect it's in the package C code or, more likely, being passed to `libcurl` as-is.)

Comment: But when I'm use the WinSCP to access in the FTP server the username has @ like a email.

Comment: I'm not saying that it isn't legal, I'm saying that perhaps it is not being parsed correctly internally. *I don't know*, and I admit that I'll be a little surprised if that is the case.

Comment: (Sorry, I don't really have any advice for you, I don't know a good workaround. I *do* know that I avoid insecure FTP whenever possible, preferring at a minimum FTPS/SFTP if not SCP or rsync. I suggest that if you have the option, look into ssh/scp/rsync options, perhaps as an alternative if you cannot get ftp working.)

Comment: Thanks I will wait for another solutions possibles.